# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm constantly getting error when i wanna insert some data

**Project Class**

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Project.findAll",
         query = "SELECT p FROM Project p"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Project.findByTitle",
                query = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.title = :title")
})
public class Project implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int projectId;

    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column
    private Date projectDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectStatusId")
    private ProjectStatus projectStatus;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "projectMemberId",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ProjectMember> memberList = new ArrayList<ProjectMember>();

    /**
     * Setters and Getters
     */
}
```

**ProjectMember Class**

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "ProjectMember.findAll",
                query = "SELECT pm FROM ProjectMember pm"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "ProjectMember.findByProject",
                query = "SELECT pm FROM ProjectMember pm WHERE pm.project = :project"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "ProjectMember.findByUser",
                query = "SELECT pm FROM ProjectMember pm WHERE pm.user = :user"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "ProjectMEmeber.findByUserAndProject",
                query = "SELECT pm FROM ProjectMember pm  WHERE pm.user = :user AND pm.project = :project")
})

public class ProjectMember implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int projectMemberId;


    @Column
    private Date activationDate;
    @Column
    private Date lastActiveDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "memberStatusId")
    private MemberStatus memberStatus;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectId")
    private Project project;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "memberRoleId")
    private MemberRole memberRole;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    /**
     * Setter and Getter
     */
}
```

that's how i run it

**ProjectController Class**

```
public String createProject(){
    project.setProjectDate(new Date());
    project.setProjectStatus(new ProjectStatusFacade().findByStatus("active"));

    ProjectMember projectMember = new ProjectMember();
    projectMember.setMemberStatus(new MemberStatusFacade().findByStatus("accepted"));
    projectMember.setMemberRole(new MemberRoleFacade().findByRole("team leader"));
    projectMember.setActivationDate(new Date());
    projectMember.setUser(userSession.getUser());

    new ProjectFacade().create(project);
    System.out.print(project);
    projectMember.setProject(project);
    new ProjectMemberFacade().create(projectMember);

    userSession.setUser(new UserFacade().findById(userSession.getUser().getUserId()));
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

and that's what i get in the end

```
 Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        ... more exceptions

    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        ... more exceptions

    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        ...more exceptions

    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`goent`.`projectmember`, CONSTRAINT `FKfyw2iinfhhsbrmqbu1sr7l93q` FOREIGN KEY (`projectMemberId`) REFERENCES `project` (`projectId`))
        ... more exceptions

    15:51:06,449 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /hibernate/pages/project-add-member.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        ... more exceptions

    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        ... more exceptions

    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        ...more exceptions
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        ... more exceptions

    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`goent`.`projectmember`, CONSTRAINT `FKfyw2iinfhhsbrmqbu1sr7l93q` FOREIGN KEY (`projectMemberId`) REFERENCES `project` (`projectId`))
        ... more exceptions
```

Using: Java, JPA, Hibernate, MySQL5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you people, finally I could fix the bug. The problem was in **Project** class, it was about incorrect mapping. Instead of telling variable to map in other class, I was pointing on PK of that class.

I wrote this

**Project class**

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectStatusId")
    private ProjectStatus projectStatus;
```

instead this

```
//Correct code
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project")
    private ProjectStatus projectStatus;
```

after this change the code started work well.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of exception is :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`goent`.`projectmember`, CONSTRAINT `FKfyw2iinfhhsbrmqbu1sr7l93q` FOREIGN KEY (`projectMemberId`) REFERENCES `project` (`projectId`))
```

Your action is violating foreign key constraint for **projectMemberId** column in **projectmember** table, which is referencing **projectId** column of **project** table as per your defined specifications.

Answer (score 0):

This is what most likely is happening.

In the `Project` entity, you are telling the persistence provider to always eagerly fetch  the `ProjectNames`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "projectMemberId",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ProjectMember> memberList = new ArrayList<ProjectMember>();
```

Then in the save method you are creating a `ProjectName` and populating it with the `Project`. Thats fine, though the list in the `Project` does not contain that newly created `ProjectName`.

The dependency has to be set on both sides, so eventually you would need to do following in your  method:

```
project.getMemberList().add(projectName);
```